# How can I configure rubber ec2 to use a single security group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I'm using rails `3.1.3` and the rubber gem `2.0.2` from:

https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber

When I run `cap rubber:create_instance` the script creates 5+ security groups on Amazon EC2, I'd like to configure it to only use one.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to pre-define the security group ahead of time, and then assign it to your instances using the `assigned_security_groups:` config in the `rubber.yml` file.

Also, make sure `auto_security_groups:` and `isolate_security_groups:` are set to false.